# Cell color covers math expression

Tags: tables, math-mode, longtable, rowcolor, cellcolor

In the following colored table there is a color issue at the 2nd row. As you can see the curly bracket is partly covered by the row color. I tried to enclose the cell in a minipage, hoping that it will be placed in front of the color.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage[no-math,cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,cmyk,table]{xcolor}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.0,BoldFont={Times New Roman Bold}]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline,longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}\arrayrulecolor{white}
\rowcolors{2}{cyan!70!gray!30}{cyan!10!gray!20}
\begin{longtable}{c|c}
\hhline{--} \rowcolor{cyan!50!gray}\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex} \textbf{N} & \textbf{Property} \\
\hline\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex} 3 & $ \sqrt{x^2}=|x|\;\;,\;\; x\in R $\\
\hline\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{7ex}  4 & 
$ \sqrt[\nu]{x^\nu}=\ccases{
|x|&  x\in R\textrm{ if }\nu\textrm{ even}\\x&  x\geq0\textrm{ and } \nu\in N} $
\\
\hhline{~-} \rowcolor{cyan!70!gray!30}  & $ \sqrt{x\cdot y}=\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{y}\;\;,\;\; x,y\geq0 $ \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}\\
\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}\multirow{-3}{*}{5} & $ \sqrt[\nu]{x\cdot y}=\sqrt[\nu]{x}\cdot\sqrt[\nu]{y}\;\;,\;\; x,y\geq0 $ \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I bring the text in front or the cellcolor at the back?

Comment: Please shorten your example. As you have a problem in row 4, row 1-3 and 5-9 are only obscuring the code. And test if you can remove mtpro2.

Comment: I created a shorted table with 3 line in order to show thw alternating color. But it is important to keep thw `mtpro2` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use \hiderowcolors in the inner tabular (the ccases):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,cmyk,table]{xcolor}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.0,BoldFont={Times New Roman Bold}]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline,longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}\arrayrulecolor{white}
\rowcolors{2}{cyan!70!gray!30}{cyan!10!gray!20}
\begin{longtable}{c|c}
\hhline{--} \rowcolor{cyan!50!gray}\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex} \textbf{N} & \textbf{Property} \\
\hline\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex} 3 & $ \sqrt{x^2}=|x|\;\;,\;\; x\in R $\\
\hline\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{7ex}  4 &
$ \sqrt[\nu]{x^\nu}=\ccases{\hiderowcolors
|x|&  x\in R\textrm{ if }\nu\textrm{ even}\\x&  x\geq0\textrm{ and } \nu\in N} $
\\
\hhline{~-} \rowcolor{cyan!70!gray!30}  & $ \sqrt{x\cdot y}=\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{y}\;\;,\;\; x,y\geq0 $ \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}\\
\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}\multirow{-3}{*}{5} & $ \sqrt[\nu]{x\cdot y}=\sqrt[\nu]{x}\cdot\sqrt[\nu]{y}\;\;,\;\; x,y\geq0 $ \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]